# c# msi setup - Custom Validation before installation

Tags: c#, .net, setup-project, custom-action

The custom UI calls a web service. If the Web Service approves the installation continues, else some message is displayed to the user that the setup cannot continue.

Using Visual Studio setup and deployment projects. Tried adding a custom action but it always executes after the install process.

How should I go about this.

Comment: You can't don't this without changing your MSI in ORCA and moving the call to custom action before copying files... somehow. To be honest, this is one of the many reasons why i tend to stay away from the deployment projects in VS. It only works in trivial cases.

Comment: VS setup projects are very limited in what they can do. Many development teams often look at other installer solutions such as installshield.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the web service validates the license key entered during install. Could you perform the key validation when the program is first run? It might save you some headaches.

Failing that, look at the BeforeInstall event of the Installer class. This executes after all information is gathered, but before the actual installation starts; the perfect place to put code that must execute before copying files. If you need those files, or other setup, to be performed in order to call the webservice, try using BeforeCommit (which still allows you to roll back the installation if validation fails).

Comment: Well FirstRuns are pretty tough to program. I want to stay away from registry and config files can be easily modified.